# Extract value between two strings in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-substr

I'm trying to extract price for each day from a tag list in SQL Developer.

This is my list (I can use another list format if needed):

```
monday12monday, tuesday567.12tuesday, friday87friday
```

I'm looking for this result :

```
tuesday
567.12

monday
12

friday
87
```

How can I get the value between two strings using "REGEXP_SUBSTR"?

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how you want to have your data returned, but this should get you on the right track. The final parameter '1' in `REGEXP_SUBSTR` fetches the first capturing group `(\d+)`, which is the number that comes after the day's name.

```
WITH tab AS (
  SELECT 'monday12monday, tuesday567tuesday, friday87friday' AS tags
  FROM DUAL
  )
SELECT 
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(tags, 'monday(\d+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS monday, 
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(tags, 'tuesday(\d+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS tuesday, 
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(tags, 'wednesday(\d+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS wednesday, 
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(tags, 'thursday(\d+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS thursday, 
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(tags, 'friday(\d+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS friday
FROM tab
```

Returns:

| MONDAY | TUESDAY | WEDNESDAY | THURSDAY | FRIDAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 567 | null | null | 87 |

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/JbbGoSgd)

Edit:
If there are decimals or thousand signs in the numbers you need to deal with, change the capture group pattern from `(\d+)` to `(\d+[\.,]?\d*[\.,]?\d*)`

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/-5nZ4fvj)

Comment: Thank you @Vvdl , it's exactly what I'm looking for, but if we have decimal numbers like 'monday12monday, tuesday567tuesday, friday87.12friday' how can we resolve it?

Comment: You can change the pattern to include an optional decimal point and maybe even a thousand sign if you need. Gets a bit measier then, but this should work: `\d+[\.,]?\d*[\.,]?\d*`

Comment: Good to hear, kindly mark it as the correct answer in case someone has the same question as you in the future.

Comment: @VvdL You don't want the backslash in front of the period inside the character class.  As it is, it will allow a backslash character as well as a period or a comma.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle you can use REGEXP_REPLACE.  If you are needing the number which is the Price as you say pulled out of your String you can Replace all non numbers with a blank and simply get back the Number from within the String using the below.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE('monday12monday', '\D', '')
```

> Returns 12

---

Update (Generic Pattern for ALL Days): I no longer have access to an Oracle DBMS however rather than replacing using REGEXP_REPLACE as I show above you can Match on All of the Groups and capture each group that is returned using a single RegEx Pattern.

```
Pattern (?:sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday)(\d+)
```

Example for Original Sting (No decimals) on RegEx101.com: https://regex101.com/r/0lb6Gu/1

Screenshot of Captured Groups using Original Pattern:
[image: Captured Groups Output (No decimals)]

---

This generic pattern will find all the days in the week and return the Captured Group(s) all in one go.

```
Pattern (?:sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday)(\d+[\.,]?\d*[\.,]?\d*)
```

Example of RegEx Pattern matching on numbers that have decimals on RegEx101.com:
https://regex101.com/r/23jP7i/1

Screenshot of Captured Groups using updated Pattern for decimals:
[image: Captured Groups Output (Decimals Included)]

Answer (score 0):

How about this method that uses CONNECT BY to parse the string by it's delimiter of "comma-space", then for each element found splits that into it's day and price components?  This way it will work no matter how many elements are in the string.

Caveat: There is no checking that day names are correct.

```
column day format a15
column price format a6

with tbl(str) as (
  select 'monday12monday, tuesday567.12tuesday, friday87friday' from dual
)
select regexp_substr(str, '(\D+)\d.*?(, |$)', 1, level, null, 1) day,
  regexp_substr(str, '\D+(\d+[.]?\d*)\D+(, |$)', 1, level, null, 1) price
from tbl
connect by level <= regexp_count(str, ', ') + 1;


DAY             PRICE 
--------------- ------
monday          12    
tuesday         567.12
friday          87    

3 rows selected.
```